# Getting values of the selected row in uiGrid angular

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have a ui-grid, that allows the user selecting one row. If a row is selected I want to bind some fields of the selected row to input fields. How is this possible?

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
data : items,
columnDefs: [
  { name: 'ITEMNO', field: 'ITEMNO', displayName: 'Pos.', enableHiding : false, width: 75 },
  { name: 'SERIALN_REQ', field: 'SERIALN_REQ', displayName: 'Serialpflichtig', enableHiding : false, width: 175  }
],
enableScrollbars : false,
enableHorizontalScrollbar : 0,
enableVerticalScrollbar : 0,
enableFullRowSelection : true,
enableRowSelection: true,
enableSelectAll: false,
multiSelect : false,
selectionRowHeaderWidth: 0,
rowHeight: 55,
enablePaginationControls: false,
paginationPageSize: 5
```

};

```
  $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
    var rows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
  }
```

In my HTML i have the following:

```
<div class="large-2 columns">
    <input type="text" disabled ng-model={{}}> <!-- here i want to bind a cell of the selected grid row -->
  </div><div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pagination class="myGrid"></div>
```

Comment: can u create a working plunker?

Comment: Hello; I have prepared a running plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/lmoKaMozQQ569n71G5C8?p=preview

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your expected one(get selected row values and bind them to the input elements).

**Use the below code**

```
$scope.rowtobebinded=undefined;
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
        $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
        var rows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();

        //aravind's code to get the selected row elements is as below
        gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
                console.log("selected row is ",row);

               //binding the row's no to the textbox

                $scope.rowtobebinded=row.entity.ITEMNO; 

        });
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/PIBpUWD47ayEYAVxlfP3?p=preview)**

Comment: Hey aravind, this helps me a lot. Is there any way to have two way binding, so that changes in the input field are directly changed in the grid and also in the workdata.items array? If not i can realize it with eventhandlers. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's cool.happy to help you. can you elaborate your query in detail?

Comment: I'm in mobile so can't figure out a solution. Will try.

Comment: Hey aravin, I have changed my plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/lmoKaMozQQ569n71G5C8?p=preview) to show you, what I mean. When you select a row in the grid and change the value of the input field the grid is updated. Now I'm using the ng-change handler of the input to update my workdata structure. Is there a better way to realize it? Thanks for your help!